# Getting Android Traceview to work

Tags: android, trace

When I try to run traceview I get:

'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
SWT folder '' does not exist.
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platfo
rm.

I can't figure out how it get it working. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running under Windows, before calling traceview first run traceview.bat (in /tools) to set some environment variables, among other things.

Also, you need to call it with an absolute path to your trace file. At least in my environment, a relative path gives me an error.

I write my trace files to the emulator's SD card, then when I want to examine them first copy them to my machine:

```
adb pull /sdcard/app.trace /app/traces
traceview.bat c:/path/app/traces/app.trace
```